# I'm trying to create an array with random integers, then reverse the array

Tags: python, arrays, random, reverse

Here's the full question: Create an array to store 5 random integers between 1 and 40. Print the sum and average of all elements in the given array. Finally, print the array backward!

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import random
print("12 random numbers between 5 and 50")
randNumbers = random.randint(5, 50)
num1=randNumbers(1)
print(num1)
randNumbers.reverse()
for element in randNumbers:
  print(element)
sum=sum+nums
avg=(round(sum/n,3))
if (nums%2==0):
  even+=1
else:
  odd+=1
print("\nSum: ",sum)
print("Average: ",round(avg,1))
```

I'm new to coding and I'm not really sure how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: what don't you know how to fix? what's going wrong?

Comment: SO is not a platform to get your homework done

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your written prompt, here is a solution:

```
import random

# five rand int between 1 and 40
randNumbers = [random.randint(1, 40) for _ in range(5)]
print(randNumbers)

# print sum stored in randNumbers
print(sum(randNumbers))

# print avg stored in randNumbers
print(sum(randNumbers)/len(randNumbers))

# print array backwards
print(randNumbers[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use **numpy** library for all these mathematical operations.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
rand_nums = np.random.randint(1,40,5)
print(f"Random integer array: {rand_nums}")
print(f"Sum: {rand_nums.sum()}")
print(f"Average: {rand_nums.mean()}")
print(f"Backwards array: {rand_nums[::-1]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the question in text, however it doesn't match your code so hopefully, this is what you wanted.

```
import random

print("12 random numbers between 5 and 50")
randNumbers = []
for i in range(0, 12):
    randNumbers.append(random.randint(1, 40))

print("Original: " + str(randNumbers))
print("Sum: " + str(sum(randNumbers)))
print("Average: " + str(sum(randNumbers) / len(randNumbers)))

randNumbers.reverse()
print("Reversed: " + str(randNumbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Long and detailed answer**

```
import random

print("12 random numbers between 5 and 50")
randNumbers = [] # initialize an empty array
for i in range(5): # create 5 times..
    randNum = random.randint(1, 40) # ..a random number between 1 and 40
    randNumbers.append(randNum) # then add it to the array
print(f"array is {randNumbers}")

# Print sum of the elements of array
s = 0 # initialize the sum s to 0
for element in randNumbers:
    s = s + element # add each element of the array to the sum s
print(f"sum is {s}")

# Print the average
size = len(randNumbers) # the size of the array
average = s / size # the average of the array
print(f"average is {average}")

# Print the array backwards
backed = []
for i in range(1, size+1):
    backed.append(randNumbers[-i])
print(f"backward array is{backed}")
```

**Short answer:**

```
import random

randNumbers = [random.randint(1, 40) for i in range(5)]
print(f"array is {randNumbers}")

s = sum(randNumbers)
print(f"sum is {s}")

avg = s / len(randNumbers)
print(f"average is {avg}")

backed = list(reversed(randNumbers))
print(f"backward array is{backed}")
```

Comment: I keep getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: yes that's what you are getting at line number 4 because `random.randint(.., ..)` on the previous line returned an integer instead of an array. also you use brackets `[ ]` instead of parentheses `( )` to access an element from an array, if that was an array.